# What (if any) is the generally accepted way of minimising the impact of the IO Monad on my code

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io-monad

I'm struggling a bit with the IO Monad. (still very much a 101 learner)

I believe I understand the excellent reasons for segregating "IO" from purely functional code, but this appears to be making my code much more complex when using clock and environment attributes. Here's an example (related to clocks):

```
timeZoneSeconds = liftA (60*) $ liftA timeZoneMinutes getCurrentTimeZone
```

Now, I have lots of other stuff to do with timeZoneSeconds -- adding, subtracting, comparing -- elsewhere in the program, and as timeZoneSeconds interacts with other bits, practically everything I'm dealing with turns into an "IO ", and thus fills my code with liftAs.

So basically I'm seeing all my pure code turning into IO-dirty code.

In all the didactic material I've seen, most of the explanations around the IO monad are of the general sort "read stuff then write stuff", without much "calculate stuff".

Is there a recommended way to minimise the impact of this?

Should I redefine all the operators I need to use liftA "under the covers"?

Or should I just get on with it?

Comment: Are you sure your function needs to use `getCurrentTimeZone`, rather than taking a `TimeZone` argument?

Comment: @chepner I'm afraid so: it does a bunch of clock calculations, and one of the options is to adjust for local time. As well as that, I want to be able to provide default program parameters via environment variables,

So the program takes it's value of "local time", in order of priority, from a command line argument, an environment variable, or the system local time as default.

Comment: Of course, environment variables are also IO String. I can see how to do this with liftA (albeit a bit tiresome), but am totally lost as to how to do this with, for example, pattern matching and guards.

Comment: Yes, values from impure sources are impure, but once you have them, you can pass them as *values* to pure functions. You can do this via `fmap`, `>>=`, or by using `do` notation. Is that an option?

Comment: `timeZoneSeconds = \tz -> 60 * timeZoneMinutes tz <$> getCurrentTimeZone` This way, all the logic is in a pure function, mapped over the impure `IO` value.

Comment: @MarkSeemann : fmap, >>=, and do are still a bit of a closed book for me.
I have one lesser, and one greater problem.
The lesser is that that I can lard my program with liftA calls ( I think) and "everything becomes IO <something>"
The harder is how on earth do I use pattern matching and guards?

Comment: @chepner : Ah, yes, but as an impure timeZoneSeconds burrows down into the rest of the program, this kind of construct has to be repeated over and over again. As functions using timeZoneSeconds give impure results, and so on down the chain.

Comment: This isn't a great example: how many times do you *really* need to fetch the same time zone from the outside world? But the idea of converting time-zone minutes to time-zone seconds is *independent* of how you actually *get* a time zone. Start by refactoring your code to isolate the pure, business logic from the I/O code, and you start to find you aren't as dependent on the `IO` module as you might have though.

Comment: @chepner : Let me explain: this is a utility for converting between a whole series of different date and time formats. For example (among a lot of other stuff), from Unix seconds to current time, maybe adjusted by a timezone. The user can specify the timezone as a run-time parameter, or can set up an environment variable, or can just use the system timezone as a default. Both of the last two bring in the IO monad. So the "business logic" is inexorably tied to the IO monad.

Comment: The value of the environment variable doesn't *change* after the program starts. As an extreme example, rather than writing your entire program as a single `IO ()` action with calls to `getEnv` scattered throughout, write a single function `f :: String -> ()`, then start your program with `main = fmap f (getEnv "VARNAME")`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. So within main I can do all the dirty work, and then pass the results, effectively clean, to my pure functions? Brilliant.

If you'd care to post that as an answer, instant acceptance!

Comment: Aside: I'd never actually come across `liftA` before - but when I looked it up, I saw it's the same as `fmap` (just restricted to Applicative functors). I'd not seen it used before, even though I have seen `liftM` (which is the same but more restricted still) in the wild. I would consider `fmap` much more idiomatic - but regardless of that, the fact you're using `liftA` everywhere shows that it can't be true that `fmap` is a closed book to you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it as dependency injection. You inject the results of the impure calls into your pure code, then use the results of the pure code to do more impure IO such as printing the result:

```hs
main = do
  env <- lookupEnv "ENV"
  tz <- getCurrentTimeZone
  let result = pureCode env tz
  putStr result
```

Your `pureCode` function doesn't have any `IO` attached.

Comment: I'd just like to say an additional "Thank you" for this answer, which finally made my brain click lifting the last clouds from my understanding of how to use the IO Monad, and opening up the World of Haskell for me.